# How to deal with component state with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been using vanilla React for a while, and have now decided to take a closer look at Redux for a new project I am doing.

At first I got the impression that **all** user activity should result in actions, with one of the main reasons being that you would be able to reconstruct any application state by just playing back the appropriate actions.

The problem with this, however, is that you put a lot of stuff in the store that in reality does not feel like application state. Stuff like "If I focus on this input, the label turns green" does not seem like state fitted for being represented in the application state of an application that is potentially composed by hundreds of components. These things make total sense with the typical todo-tutorial, but it can be difficult to see how it will turn out in a more complex scenario.

Then I read some more, and found that the general opinion, backed by creator Dan Abramov, is that you should usually combine local component state with the application state (store). "Whatever seems least awkward" seemed to be the rule of thumb for where to store state.

On one hand this makes total sense: The things that are really application state, and are relevant for multiple components should be in the store, while the strictly presentational details that only concerns one single component should be handled using normal react state. On the other hand this approach confuses me a bit, because of what I wrote in the beginning: Isn't a big part of the point with redux that you avoid having the state distributed among the components, and that you are able to recreate state by just storing the actions?

I hope someone can shed some light on this concern, because it has been bothering me, and it is something I think I should get a solid opinion about before trying to build something complex with redux.

Answer (score 3):

What state you put where is entirely up to you.  Sometimes it may make sense to put everything in Redux, sometimes it may make sense to keep stuff in a component.  I recently saw some good rules-of-thumb:

- Do other parts of the application care about that data?
- Do you need to be able to derive further data from that data?
- Is the same data being used to drive multiple components/features?
- Is there value to you, to being able to restore the state to a given point in time (ie: time travel / debugging)?
- Do you want to cache the data, ie: reload it from state if it's already there instead of requesting it again?

(Credit to https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4w04to/when_using_redux_should_all_asynchronous_actions/d63u4o8 for that list.)

Also see the Redux FAQ on this topic: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state .